# Why do I keep an exception message when ever I run my code on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

When ever I run this code on eclipse, it gives me this exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at HW2.howManyTimesDoNumbersIncrease(HW2.java:221)
    at HW2.main(HW2.java:190)
```

Please run on your programs tell me what's wrong with my program. PLEASE HELP!

code

```
public class HW2 {

    // Class variables
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING ARRAY!!
    public static int[] first = { 3391, 3391, 3391, 0, -1036, -3676, -4840,
            3798, 0, 0, -1350, -1350, 4320, -265, -265, 3222, 3222, -77, 0, 0,
            -3344, -3018, 1479, -2085, -2085, -2085, -2085, -2085, 0, 3205,
            -3775, 1165, 1165, 0, 0, 747, -1584, -3320, 3301, 0, -194, 1595,
            1595, 0, 440, 722, 722, 722, 722, 3130, -2978, 4215, 4215, 4215,
            766, 766, -157, -3206, 0, 0, -2630, 3348, 3348, 0, 0, -3942, -1545,
            326, 326, 4901, -4048, 0, -1388, -1388, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4604, -2998, 0,
            -963, 0, 2555, -3578, 875, 410, 410, 2610, -4244, -4244, -4244,
            3474, 4073, -3865, -1618, -467, 4630, -2874, -2874, 1660, 1660,
            4236, 4236, 0, -1532, 2544, -1869, -1869, 0, -4064, 3383, -1648,
            -4642, -4090, -4090, -4090, 1611, -587, 0, 0, 0, 551, 551, 551,
            551, 0, 1418, 2953, 3892, -547, -547, 1847, 1719, -3701, 2335,
            3193, -4723, -3818, -3818, 1140, 1140, 4154, 3947, 0, 0, -2992,
            -2992, 4351, 4351, 213, 213, 213, -2177, 3029, 1275, -1086, -4651,
            -4651, 3380, 669, -3962, -3962, -3962, 0, 0, 0, 1764, 496, -4707,
            1554, 4758, 0, 280, 3979, -4812, 1678, 43, -979, -2610, 725, 725,
            4653, -2571, -2571, -4435, -4799, 4383, -2089, -2089, -2089, -2089,
            -2089, 4735, -3959, 3860, -3702, 2334, -3329, -3329, -3329, 3786,
            3786, -2057, 4172, 4172, -787, 31, 31, 1702, 3410, 3410, 2216,
            -1739, 770, 770, -861, 2107, 2107, -2089, 2432, 2432, 2543, 3422,
            2728, 2728, -1292, 3601, 0, 0, 1218, -1979, -2632, -2632, -214,
            -214, 0, -770, 4007, -4358, -1776, -867, -3334, -4020, 997, 3607,
            -794, 3828, 1740, 0, -38, -38, 870, 870, 870, 1691, 0, -3390, -290,
            -290, 4400, -2152, -1433, -1433, -265, -265, -4259, -2589, 4895,
            735, 735, 3246, -3913, -4163, -4163, 2084, -4086, -4086, 4486,
            2632, 2614, 3069, -3298, -4401, -4881, 2646, 2646, -1323, 4204, 0,
            0, -4828, 2662, 470, -3909, -3909, -787, -3675, -3675, -3861,
            -3861, 0, 0, -3093, -1750, -59, -3406, -1558, 2399, 4791, 2491,
            1287, 1287, 0, -3019, -1008, 0, 797, 1185, -439, -439, 0, 2470,
            3553, -4848, 2519, -3162, -2911, -2556, 2229, 1412, 0, 0, -350, 0,
            0, -3403, -3403, 3270, 3270, 2898, 2898, 2898, -1620, 2507, 1180,
            1180, 384, -4952, 2221, 3447, 3447, 3447, 3447, 1725, -2329, -2329,
            -902, 4760, 1092, 1092, 0, 420, 4324, 2048, 99, -3813, -1376,
            -1376, -1376, -1376, 564, 3107, -852, 3953, 0, -364, 3388, -2440,
            -2440, 1077, 0, 4340, -2646, 4644, -266, -409, 492, -3000, 1073,
            -1851, 1950, 1950, -1583, 4937, 3840, 3840, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2505,
            -1990, 1159, 1797, 0, 0, -146, 4521, -1095, -2776, 0, 2606, -3931,
            -3931, -3931, 2557, 2557, 2557, 2579, 1438, -980, 498, 0, -3139,
            4407, 4407, -9, 2287, 1633, -3942, -3942, -872, 2193, 0, 3894,
            -1069, -1069, -3094, 3376, 3376, 0, 0, -3017, -3017, -4278, -445,
            -4408, 2724, 0, 2678, 2398, -1388, 4676, 2958, 2958, 971, 3491,
            3491, 3793, 531, 0, -1278, -3552, -4599, -3125, 2763, -2599, 4505,
            -2964, -2964, 0, -1208, 0, 0, 3727, 3727, 0, 0, -562, 0, 1377,
            -239, -2957, -4129, -4129, -4129, -3265, 3275, -4140, -4140, -4140,
            2421, 2421, 2421, -1462, 1507, 1507, 1507, -4975, 2055, 341, 341,
            -2183, -2183, -2183, 348, -2964, -2964, 967, 3650, 3650, 0, 545, 0,
            -3443, 3970, -1816, 4905, 4905, -621, -621, -2103, 33, 1260, 1260,
            -3546, -3546, -922, -3519, 0, 0, 2382, 3425, -3021, -922, 4183,
            989, -1425, -1425, 0, 0, 0, 1784, 1784, 1784, 841, -616, -616,
            4488, 3820, 3820, 3820, 3768, 1050, -680, 3757, 2482, -2635, 1408,
            1408, -3100, -4242, -4242, -50, -50, -2013, -2013, -2013, -484,
            -4434, -4434, -4434, 1562, 1562, 1100, -763, -2597, 3203, 3203,
            3203, 2512, 2512, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -1100, -3462,
            -3859, -1716, 4833, -1843, -1843, 421, 867, 4661, 566, 566, 2885,
            2885, 2176, -639, 4285, 4285, 4285, 3229, 3229, 0, 0, -3298, -3298,
            0, -1452, -3456, -1922, -1370, 4485, 4485, 422, 422, 322, 2044,
            3156, 1588, -2406, -2406, -2406, 2136, 4283, 2991, -969, 0, 0,
            -369, -369, 0, 4202, 85, 85, 41, -1917, -1917, -773, -3183, 1245,
            -1991, 2160, -2860, -2480, 2657, 2657, 2657, 2657, 4975, 760, 2750,
            -3876, 3738, 1255, -3385, -1946, 0, -1511, -4376, -3181, -3830,
            1862, 1862, -3265, -3265, -3265, 3379, 956, 4833, 4833, -969, 911,
            421, 421, -4156, 4045, 2478, -4151, -2899, -2721, -2721, -2721,
            -2399, -4976, 2447, 2447, 3534, 0, 0, -4856, -3308, 4592, 4592,
            2969, 2969, -4851, 201, 47, -1960, -1960, -1960, -1960, 0, -1181,
            -4296, 0, 0, 0, -87, 0, -4796, -1630, -3903, 720, 720, 0, 0, 4341,
            4341, -911, -911, -2980, -2222, -2222, -2222, 0, 0, 0, -1198, 1609,
            2435, 0, 1623, 1623, 0, 1256, -3594, 3234, -316, -2103, 3289, 0,
            3765, 2156, 2156, 2158, 2158, 2158, -1958, -526, -2735, -2735, 98,
            3157, 4056, 3613, -3940, -3940, 1548, 2735, -4805, -475, -4285,
            -4115, 0, -806, 813, -2120, -2120, 2910, -1645, -1645, 926, 926,
            -1873, -1873, 556, 556, -1857, 2339, 0, 4214, 3887, 2540, -4717,
            3958, 3958, 3958, -963, -963, 0, 4882, -4490, -3035, -4224, -263,
            3646, 894, 0, 0, 0, 2349, 2493, -1124, 1358, -4463, 3136, 1304,
            -4621, -4621, -4621, 3845, 3845, -368, -4793, 1983, -1186, -1200,
            4909, 4909, 4909, 3178, -3670, -42, -1968, 3403, 812, -38, -1570,
            -2693, -674, -4884, 2048, 2276, 1820, 1820, 1820, 79, -1316, -834,
            -477, 0, -1873, 3307, 4222, -234, 961, -2372, 4199, 4199, -1714,
            4668, 4668, -1556, -1556, -4089, 4389, 4026, 0, -3158, -1678,
            -1678, -2960, -2960, -2960, -3427, -3427, 4947, 0, 0, -138, -4103,
            -3391, -3391, 0, 0, -3016, -3990, 4396, -1099, 3406, -3632, -2860,
            69, 4315, 4690, -891, -48, 0, 1470, -3638, 0, 4735, 4735, 631, 631,
            -4769, 2231, 2231, 2231, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1903, 0, 0, 0, 2195, 4142,
            -1396, -1756, 2954, -4427, 178, 4857, 4813, 4813, 547, 547, 547,
            2923, -4627, 1836, -3243, -3243, 3002, 3002, 2600, 2600, 2600, 971,
            0, 0, -1, -1, 4351, 4351, 4351, 2351, -2209, -1771, 3061, -3381,
            -3381, -4978, 923, -2470, 512, 512, 2468, 3987, 3987, 3987, 1993,
            -3338, -3338, 0, -1696, 3087, 1165, -4491, -4146, -4146, -2412,
            -4969, 938, 1351, -40, 0, 4035, -3848, 4345, 0, 1176, 2887, 4333,
            4333, 4281, 4281, -354, -354, -371, 4692, 415, -990, -975, 3098,
            3098, 0, 0, 0, 4626, };

    public static int[] second = { 0, 3113, 3352, 3352, 340, -2872, -2872,
            4976, 4976, 2541, 4330, -2917, 2139, 2139, 3853, 1393, 4730, 4730,
            -1734, -1734, 4932, 4663, 0, 0, -4982, 1489, 1489, 1489, -65, -65,
            -883, 203, 203, 0, 2072, 2072, 2072, -3012, -4878, -225, -225, 0,
            0, -3344, -4995, 2638, 2638, -1350, -1350, -2767, 0, 0, -4759,
            -4759, 1377, 2545, 2439, 2439, 794, 794, 1342, -2773, -2026, 4404,
            -4974, -4974, 3022, 3022, -159, 2154, -3037, -3383, -3383, 0,
            -2319, 1905, 0, 2325, -708, -1766, 1205, 1205, -152, 0, 3335, 0, 0,
            -303, 1567, 1567, -2042, 0, -4032, 658, -299, 3411, 693, 1213, 0,
            -3541, 2366, 2366, 2366, 249, -2454, -2984, -3969, -3869, -3869,
            -2230, -1132, 1913, 0, -3508, -3508, 1406, -3917, -3917, -703,
            -4040, 3070, 3070, 3504, 331, -3142, 3014, 0, 0, -3759, -3977,
            4875, -2916, -2916, 1003, 1547, -501, 0, -881, -2926, -2810, 712,
            712, 712, 4570, 1726, 0, -2736, 4358, -3164, 2856, 2592, 0, 0, 0,
            3972, 3972, -3143, -3143, -1463, -3342, -3342, -3342, -4867, -4867,
            4776, -2911, -2911, -2911, -55, 2425, 2425, 2425, 2685, 2685,
            -4424, 0, 0, 4933, -402, 0, -4278, -3043, 2496, 2496, 2496, 3768,
            1678, 1795, 3979, 0, 4131, 4131, 0, -1521, 2763, 2763, -3518,
            -3518, -3995, 0, 0, -4799, 559, 275, -4180, 0, -3733, -3733, -3704,
            -3704, 1890, 168, 2795, 2795, -1831, -1831, 1596, -893, -71, -512,
            -1825, -1825, -1825, -2983, -4707, -4652, 806, 4826, 4959, -2488,
            652, 652, -1725, -3984, 0, 696, 4408, -3788, 3764, 0, 1316, -2776,
            0, 1849, -2470, -4063, 0, 2248, -2183, -2183, 0, -3837, -3837,
            -339, 1792, -2659, 358, 0, -4600, 2123, 2123, 3256, -1720, -1720,
            -1720, 4045, 4045, 3011, -3275, 0, 0, 4615, -4657, 4560, 4560,
            -3570, 0, 0, 0, -3438, 1677, 3475, 3475, 3475, -3965, 3509, 3070,
            3167, 442, -630, 2551, 0, 3260, -2432, -2432, -1347, 4358, -85,
            -85, 485, 3740, 1675, 1124, 1124, 2627, 4994, -2404, 1638, 4453,
            -1065, -609, 4294, -1169, 4593, -225, -225, -225, 1077, -60, -4331,
            1608, 1876, 3035, -3045, -3045, 4418, -3622, -3622, 0, 0, 0, 4207,
            4207, -430, 0, -669, 0, 0, 0, 630, 630, 4581, -1534, 635, -109,
            -109, -109, -2013, -2208, 3685, 3685, 585, 585, 585, 4999, 4395,
            4395, -3385, -2789, 2014, 0, -1382, -2869, -2869, 0, 0, -1884,
            -1782, 3576, 3576, -3926, 0, 4259, -4770, -4770, -4770, 609, 0,
            4005, 4005, 2970, -883, -4679, -12, -12, -890, -2431, 2076, 3011,
            -1787, 237, -2781, -2917, -558, 1163, -4513, 3420, 3420, 4370,
            4370, 1024, 1024, 672, 672, 0, 4570, 4570, 4570, -2277, 882, 3456,
            0, 0, 0, 3594, -3209, -3133, -3852, 3045, 3045, -4142, -4142, 2054,
            -4471, 1997, 0, 1852, 3386, -1709, -2972, 0, -4104, 178, -1491,
            3984, 3984, 3984, 3984, 3984, 3984, 3984, 0, 0, 3692, 0, 2964,
            1548, -1106, 4484, 0, 0, 2600, -2594, 3632, 3632, 2253, 532, 210,
            -81, 0, 0, 0, -74, 280, -2884, 1715, -1045, -431, -431, 3357, 3695,
            3695, 3695, 0, 385, 385, -307, -4858, -2792, 874, -465, -833, 74,
            74, 74, -742, -742, -742, 441, 0, -4041, -4041, -4106, 360, 0, 620,
            620, 620, 620, 2498, 4531, -1598, -4643, 3714, 3714, 1309, 3206,
            3206, 3542, -2609, -2609, -1165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2333, 3554, 3554,
            3554, 3554, 1828, -3542, -3542, -629, 1589, 2508, -1528, -799,
            -799, 0, -733, -4520, 2242, 2242, 2226, 1972, 4800, 4800, 4471,
            -1618, 4229, 4229, 4459, 0, 3, 3, 3171, 4739, -279, 3049, -1220, 0,
            113, -2272, 2675, -4903, -2498, -3219, -3903, -2275, -2040, 0,
            -1973, 0, -4041, 3277, 3277, 3277, -3240, -669, -669, -669, -4814,
            -3918, 2542, 4695, 4695, 2873, 2926, 2789, 2789, -2080, -4957,
            -4957, -4603, 4290, 2043, 3375, -827, -827, 4175, 185, 185, 1932,
            -2172, -2172, -3174, -4826, -4813, 3740, -4327, -2278, 0, -1875,
            -1875, -3950, -4829, -261, 3432, -1274, -1274, -2502, -1351, -4286,
            -4898, 1371, -988, 416, -1065, 76, 4318, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2579, -2579,
            0, 0, 0, 1918, 2781, 2781, -2986, -4446, 1261, 1261, 1261, 1261,
            1261, 4286, -2951, 4707, 4707, 4466, 4466, -772, 4691, -4913,
            -1642, -3092, -3092, 0, 565, 565, -2026, -2026, 0, 742, 742, -3122,
            -4087, -4087, -4087, -4119, -4097, -175, -175, -175, 1776, 1776,
            1776, 561, 0, 0, -838, 3071, 3071, 3654, 3654, 708, 708, 4532, 0,
            3213, 4535, 4535, 1969, -2980, 2485, -4969, -4969, -1097, -39,
            3932, 3116, -1807, 0, 0, -2869, 1274, 1274, 1700, 1700, 1700, 3985,
            -2590, 2896, 0, 3012, -2029, -102, 631, 631, -1159, -1159, 394,
            2800, -4835, 1446, -1185, -1185, -4091, -4380, -1061, 463, -20,
            2527, -4468, 1062, 4188, 33, -4370, -4370, 0, -4230, 4405, 0, 0, 0,
            0, -1644, 178, 0, -369, -369, -4085, -3883, -3883, 2150, 633,
            -4599, -4599, 0, -3318, -4545, 4759, 62, -865, 1716, 1716, -3735,
            -1204, -1204, -435, -779, 0, 3438, 0, 0, -567, 0, -927, -3647, 0,
            -3959, -3959, 0, 1074, 2355, 2887, 4760, 0, 0, -1100, -1100, -4905,
            -4905, -2193, -2193, -2193, -2193, 1046, -2771, -2832, -831, -3156,
            -3156, 4648, -4179, 1680, 435, 649, 1309, 1309, -1893, 1823, 1823,
            1823, 1823, 0, 0, -414, -4631, 1388, -70, 4216, 1789, 1789, -3121,
            0, 3960, 2665, -727, 1551, 0, 0, 1544, -4000, -567, 212, 212, -186,
            -1243, 0, 0, -3411, -3411, -3411, 4965, -4064, -456, 4987, 4987,
            2007, 2007, -190, -1634, -1634, 1537, 689, -3040, -844, -3000, 367,
            -1076, -1076, 4581, -2278, -1899, -3602, -1449, -4000, -894, 985,
            -957, 4384, -3149, -3747, 2391, 3940, 0, 0, 1487, -201, 3961, 3961,
            -4910, 0, 0, 0, -2486, -2486, -3592, 4360, 2815, 2815, -1664,
            -1664, 3135, -4170, 0, 0, 504, -2385, 0, 0, -354, -1862, -1035,
            231, 231, 231, 0, -1034, 4996, 336, 2447, 0, 2563, -1115, -1115,
            -357, -143, -3451, -3451, 0, -857, -857, -2057, -134, -1162, -4728,
            -4728, -4728, 0, 3608, 3608, 3608, 0, 0, 0, 2559, 1068, -2393,
            -563, 4619, 4619, -174, -174, -2133, -1469, 2501, -2875, 0, 910,
            -235, 0, 0, 0, -4155, 0, 3526, 2167, -1872, 4703, 3555, 3555, 0,
            -1864, 0, -2865, -2765, 1606, -543, 3742, 3742, -932, 4973, 1684,
            0, 4239, 3537, 787, 3399, 3399, 3399, 3399, 2149, -1940, -478,
            2748, 4713, 2538, 3542, 2925, 3257, -2152, -2152, -3643, -3643,
            1381, -4229, -1835, 32, 32, 396, 0, };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("howManyTimesIsFirstGreaterThanSecond() = "
                + howManyTimesIsFirstGreaterThanSecond(first, second));
        System.out.println("howManyTimesDoNumbersIncrease()        = "
                + howManyTimesDoNumbersIncrease(first));
        System.out.println("averageOfAllEvenNumbers()              = "
                + averageOfAllEvenNumbers(second));
        System.out.println("firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger()  = "
                + firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger(first, 0));
        int[] subsequence = new int[] { 2398, -1388, 4676, 2958, 2958, 971, 3491,
                3491, 3793, 531, 0, -1278, -3552 };
        System.out.println("subsequenceStart()                     = "
                + subsequenceStart(first, subsequence));
    }

    // easy
    // returns the number of times first[i] > second [i]
    // you can assume first.length == second.length
    public static int howManyTimesIsFirstGreaterThanSecond(int[] first, int[] second){
        // implement
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<first.length;i++){
            if(first[i]>second[i]){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    // easy
    // returns the number of times is input[i + 1] > input[i]
    public static int howManyTimesDoNumbersIncrease(int[] input) {
        // implement
        int times=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
            if(input[i+1]>input[i]){
                times++;
            }
        }
        return times;
    }

    // medium
    // returns the average of all even numbers
    public static double averageOfAllEvenNumbers(int[] input) {
        // implement
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<input.length;i++){
            if(input[i]%2==0){
                sum+=input[i];
            }
        }
        return (double)sum/input.length;
    }

    // hard
    // returns the first index of the longest repeating sequence of x in input
    // for example, if input = {0,0,1,1,1,0,1} and x = 1, then output = 2
    public static int firstIndexOfLongestRepeatingInteger(int[] input, int x) {
        // implement
        return 1;
    }

    // hard
    // returns the first index where the subsequence is found in sequence
    // you can assume subsequence.length < sequence.length
    // you can assume subsequence is in sequence
    public static int subsequenceStart(int[] sequence, int[] subsequence) {
        // implement
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `first` and `second` have the same length?

Comment: `input[i + 1]` probably cause the error. maximum possible index you can access is `input[input.length-1]` but you use `input[input.length]`

Comment: if(first[i]>second[i]){ will only work if first.length == second.length or else it will produce an arrayindexoutofbounds. This is because it would be iterating over a nonexistent array.

Comment: It is a hw assignment. I assume they have the same length b/c my professor gave me the template of the code and he wants the class to fill out the code for each method with instructions give in the comments. How should I change input[i +1]? cause my professor wants me to know how many times the number increases comparing the current array element to the next array element. the first method is okay. the exception message is coming from the second method

Comment: you only need `for(int i=0;i<input.length-1;i++){`  for example let's say you have `4` elements in array then you compare `3rd` element with `3rd+1` which is last element.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! it make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    if(input[i+1]>input[i]){
        times++;
    }
}
```

You have to add a test here because input[i+1] is out of bound of course.

For example :

input.length = 1000;
input[999 + 1] is out of bound because the last index of your array is 999

Here is the code you'll have to add

```
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
            if (i == input.length - 1) break;
            if(input[i+1]>input[i]){
            times++;
        }
    }
```

You break from the loop once all the indexes have been tested.

EDIT : For the clarity, I put this example when I could've just changed the condition in the loop. I choose this one because it speaks more.

Here's the other solution

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length() - 1 ; i++){
    (...)
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome ! Don"t forget to validate my answer ! :)

Comment: It will be faster to change the top limit in the loop so it does not check on every iteration:     for(int i=0;i<input.length - 1;i++){

Comment: Hey @ItsAllAndrew , do not forget to validate the answer ! Important for the community and it is also a way to say thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are of equal lengths. However, because array indeces start at ZERO, the last index in the array should be 999.

```
        if(input[i+1]>input[i]){
            times++;
        }
```

999 is less than the array's length, but 999 + 1 is 1000, which is out of bounds.